# Which Fonts and Colors Option(s) Controls the Appearance of Tool Tips in the Code Window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2015. My tool tips used to be boring (and readable) black text on a white background. Now, colors that apply to tokens in the code window apparently apply here, too. I've been through the list of choices half a dozen times and can't figure out which one controls the background of this popup window, illustrated below. Which settings should I look at? And I suppose, a follow-up question would be "what do I call this popup window?", as I suspect knowing that name would have answered my question.

[image: Code Window with aforementioned popup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup window is called "Editor Tooltip" but I'm afraid you only can edit the 'Plain text'-part of the window, in your case "local variable". I'm afraid your best bet is to go with the Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor [link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b)